# Transcoding from H.264/AVC to HEVC in Asterisk 11

Tags: c, h.264, asterisk, codec, hevc

Is it possible to develop a H.264 to HEVC transcoder for asterisk as it doesn't have native support for H.265/HEVC ? If so, how would I put my transcoder into use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to put in a comment...

[asterisk?](http://www.asterisk.org/)? Answering without knowing anything about that FW. I'd say no, since although H.264 and HEVC share a large set of functions they are fundamentally different. In H.264 the fundamental area to operate on is the macroblock. The MB concept doesn't exist anylonger in HEVC.

Then again, it's software and anything is possible but the workload here is just humongous...

Comment: Hmmmm...I understand your reasoning and I've been documenting myself in the meantime, and I believe it has no practical value doing that. Well my question was if it is possible, not asking the solution, so I think I'll accept your answer.